# jQuery validation to ensure that at least one radiobutton value is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I've a form that has two questions. The first question asks whether the product value is greater than a fixed certain amount and the second question asks if the product value is less than the fixed amount. When the user tries to submit the form, the form should be validated to confirm that at least one question has been answered as yes. If both questions are answered as no, the form valid property `$("#form").valid()` should be false and a div containing an error message should be displayed on the page. How can I achieve this using jQuery validation?

A simplified version of the form looks something like

```
<form id="billing" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for "billAmountLess">Value is less than 1000</label>
        <input id="billAmountLessY" name="billAmountLess" type="radio" required value="True">
        <label for "billAmountLessY">Yes</label>
        <input id="billAmountLessN" name="billAmountLess" type="radio" required value="False">
        <label for "billAmountLessN">No</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for "billAmountMore">Value exceeds 1000</label>
        <input id="billAmountMoreY" name="billAmountMore" type="radio" required value="True">
        <label for "billAmountMoreY">Yes</label>
        <input id="billAmountMoreN" name="billAmountMore" type="radio" required value="False">
        <label for "billAmountMoreN">No</label>
    </div>
    <div id="errorDiv" style="display:none">Error!!!!
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

The jQuery validation that I'm trying is

```
$('#billing').validate({
    rules: {
        billAmountMore: {
            equalTo: {
                param: '#billAmountMoreY',
                depends: function(element) {
                    $("errorDiv").show();
                    return $("#input[name='billAmountLess']:checked").val() == "false"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohncmLu5/2/) for this.

Comment: Why you must create two questions with two options each, and all of that is correlated? I would just put one checkbox indicating if it's exceed 1000 or not.. Is there any technical reason behind this?

Comment: I agree it doesn't make much sense in this scenario. I've simplified the question here. But we do need two sets of questions as per our requirements. It is like, the user can have something exceeding the limit or something that is below the limit, or multiple things that meet both criteria. But user cannot select neither. We check that in the backend to perform few actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    function validate(){
        console.log($("input[name='billAmountLess']:checked").val());
        console.log($("input[name='billAmountMore']:checked").val());
    }
```

to retrieve the radio button value.

In your code this line:

```
return $("#input[name='billAmountLess']:checked").val() == "false";
```

should  remove the "#" before 'input' as it's indicating the 'id' of an element. Maybe that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can do this in custom validation function. Update your form tag -

```
<form id="billing" onsubmit="return validate();" method="POST">
```

Then -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){
    var billLess = $("input[name='billAmountLess']:checked").val();
    var billMore = $("input[name='billAmountMore']:checked").val();
    if(billLess == "False" && billMore == "False"){
      $("#errorDiv").show();
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```